# $scope.getlanguage is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, post

Hello sorry for a nob question But i am trying to learn angularjs here i implemented a function and trying to calling it on a page load 
here is my function

```
$scope.getlanguage = function () {
        console.log('bind testing')
        $http.get('/GetLanguage')
            .success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.getlanguage = data;
            }).error(function () {
            });
    }
```

And I have applied it on a page load using

```
$scope.getlanguage();
```

But after the page load it shows a error that **$scope.getlanguage** is not a function.
I don;t know why please help U am attaching the error also which i am getting it from console of firefox.
[image]

please help

Comment: show your html please

Comment: if my guess correct your calling the function before function declaration you need to call it after function declaration

Answer (score 1):

You should use some other variable for binding data since you already have a method variable for that

```
$scope.getlanguage = function () {
        console.log('bind testing')
        $http.get('/GetLanguage')
            .success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.myData= data; // <----here 
            }).error(function () {
      });
  }
```

Comment: execlty you just bang the question

Answer (score 0):

as i said in comments you need to call `$scope.getlanguage()` after declaration 
see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJGOM98n8bMNPTMWEAKj?p=preview) please comment line 13 and uncomment line 7 then you can see your error